# Filter results based on selected option in dropdown box / slider?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to figure out how to basically check the value of what has been selected in a dropdown box and return all results that meet the criteria from the database i.e. if the user selects the option in the dropdown `Up to 5 years old`, the database should be searched and return all cars that have a `CarAge` of 2009 or later.

I have the following in my controller:

```
if ($this->input->post())
    {
        $carBrand = $this->input->post('brand');
        $carModel = $this->input->post('model');
        $carColor = $this->input->post('colour');
        $carminPrice = $this->input->post('minPrice');
        $carminEngine = $this->input->post('minEngine');
        $carMiles = $this->input->post('miles');
        $carAge = $this->input->post('age');
        $maxPriceString = $this->input->post('maxPrice');
        $maxEngineString = $this->input->post('maxEngine');
        $searchKeywordString = $this->input->post('searchkeyword');
        $this->load->model("cars");
        $data['results'] = $this->cars->searchCars($carBrand, $carModel, $carColor, $carminPrice, $carminEngine, $carMiles, $carAge, $maxPriceString, $maxEngineString, $searchKeywordString);
        $this->load->view('searchresults.php', $data);
    } 
    else 
    {
        $this->load->view('search.php'); //display success view
    }
    }
```

Then in my model I have this:

```
public function searchCars($carBrand, $carAge, $carModel, $carColor, $carminPrice, $carminEngine, $carMiles, $carAge, $maxPriceString, $maxEngineString, $searchKeywordString)
{

    //Get the current Year
    $currentYear = date('Y');

    //Subtract the number of years we want to take off
    $startYear = $currentYear - $carAge;

    //Search the database where CarAge is greater than the start year
    $this->db->where('CarYear >=', $startYear);
    $this->db->like('CarMiles', $carMiles);
    $this->db->like('CarMake', $carBrand);
    $this->db->like('CarModel', $carModel);
    $this->db->like('CarColor', $carColor);
    $this->db->like('CarPrice', $minPriceString);
    $this->db->like('CarEngine', $minEngineString);
    $this->db->like('CarPrice', $maxPriceString);
    $this->db->like('CarEngine', $maxEngineString);
    $this->db->like('CarModel', $searchKeywordString);
    $query = $this->db->get('cars');
    return $query->result();
}
}
```

The age part of the form looks like this:

```
<label>Age:</label>
<select name="age">
<option value>Any</option>
<option value="1">Up to 1 year old</option>
<option value="2">Up to 2 years old</option>
<option value="3">Up to 3 years old</option>
<option value="4">Up to 4 years old</option>
<option value="5">Up to 5 years old</option>
<option value="6">Up to 6 years old</option>
<option value="7">Up to 7 years old</option>
<option value="8">Up to 8 years old</option>
<option value="9">Up to 9 years old</option>
<option value="10">Up to 10 years old</option>
<option value="11">Over 10 years old</option>
</select>
```

Example of the minimum price slider:

```
<li>
<label>Min. Price:</label>
<input class="slider" oninput="amount.value=rangeInput.value" type="range" id="rangeInput" name="minPrice" min="0" max="10000" value="0" step="500">
<span class="output">
$
<output name="amount" for="rangeInput">0</output>
</span>
</li>
```

I am not entirely sure how to basically check the value of the dropdown against the age in the database field and return results based on this. What is happening is because I have multiple sliders and dropdowns on the search form, none of the filters are working i.e. no results are returned whatsoever when trying to search.

Comment: how is stored the car age on your database? Is it a date or a integer in days?

Comment: It's stored as a year i.e. 2009 `int(4)`

Answer (score 0):

You want to change your model function to subtract the number of years the user selected from the current year.  Then once you have the start year you want to to search the database for any car where their age is greater than the start year.

Below is an example

```
public function searchCars($carAge, $carMiles)
{
    //Get the current Year
    $currentYear = date('Y');

    //Subtract the number of years we want to take off
    $startYear = $currentYear - $carAge;

    //Search the database where CarAge is greater than the start year
    $this->db->where('CarAge >=', $startYear);
    $this->db->like('CarMiles', $carMiles);
    $query = $this->db->get('cars');
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: So would this work along with other criteria i.e. I have other variables in there for searching for cars i.e. `$this->db->like('CarColor', $carColor);` and not just the age and miles. I wouldn't have to remove that would I? I basically have multiple drop-down boxes and sliders to search for cars based on multiple criteria.

Comment: @user3429767 Yes that would work, you'd just add that to your query

Comment: The problem is I have multiple sliders and dropdown boxes for search filtering and when I search I get no results returned for a lot of things and I don't know why. Obviously the code is too long to post here but I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Edited my original submission to show what I mean a bit better. Some of the field names are duplicated because I have one field for the price but have a slider to set the minimum price and the maximum price.

Comment: I've added multiple criteria to be searched based on the names given to the dropdown / slider elements on the form, but when I choose the criteria and search there are no results being returned.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what the issue is as to why no results are being shown. Is there something wrong with the search criteria for the database?